# Upgrading android gradle plugin from 4.1.3 to 7.0.4 causes gradle process crashes when running lintDebug

Tags: android-lint

I am trying to upgrade my Android Gradle plugin from 4.1.3 to 7.0.4 also lint version to 30.0.4

I am using Gradle version 7.3.3

My Gradle daemon crashes now while running lint target on CI process with error

```
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

Here is my gradel.properties file.

I tried various options android.experimental.runLintInProcess, android.experimental.lint.heapSize

discussed in this issue, without success.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178631052

Has anyone seen this issue

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8g -Xms512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx8g" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When set to true, Gradle will try to reuse outputs from previous builds
org.gradle.caching=true

# Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring projects
org.gradle.configureondemand=true

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode
org.gradle.parallel=true

# When configured, Gradle will use a maximum of the given number of workers
# 4 is good for a max for CI and running junit tests in parallel
org.gradle.workers.max=4

# Allowing to avoid Kotlin recompilation when the changes in Java do not affect Kotlin code
kotlin.incremental.usePreciseJavaTracking=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.uniquePackageNames=true
kapt.use.worker.api=true
org.gradle.unsafe.watch-fs=true
#https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178631052
#android.experimental.runLintInProcess=false
#android.experimental.lint.heapSize=1G
```

Answer (score 0):

It's OOM issue with Gradle Daemon. Setting these 6 bits in `application.properties` should work fine.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8g
kotlin.daemon.jvmargs=-Xmx8g
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score -1):

The AGP 7.0.x reqire Gradle version 7.0.2

see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility

Comment: I am using gradle 7.3.3 that should meet that requirement?

Comment: No. The gradle version is restricted. It MUST be 7.0.2+

Comment: 7.3.3 is grater than 7.0.2 so it is supposed to work...?